# Rethinkdb .net update value

Tags: c#, rethinkdb

I'm looking at updating stored values in a RethinkDB using the [C# RethinkDB.Driver](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver) library and I'm just not getting it right.

I can achieve an update by getting the result, altering that object then making a separate call to update with that object. When there are many calls to a record to update like this, the value being updated elsewhere whilst the application is working with the record.

```
TestingObject record = r.Db("test").Table("learning").Get("c8c54346-e35f-4025-8641-7117f12ebc5b").Run(_conn);

record.fieldNameIntValue = record.fieldNameIntValue + 1;

var result = r.Db("test").Table("learning").Get("c8c54346-e35f-4025-8641-7117f12ebc5b").Update(record).Run(_conn);
```

I've been trying something along these lines :

```
var result = r.Db("test").Table("learning").Get("c8c54346-e35f-4025-8641-7117f12ebc5b").Update(row => row["fieldNameIntValue"].Add(1)).Run(_conn);
```

but the result errors with `Inserted value must be an OBJECT (got NUMBER):101` which suggests this is only passing the field value back instead of updating the object.

Ideally I'd like to update multiple columns at once, any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [T Resudek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494933/t-resudek) [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35978075/2717691) and a clearer head helped emphasised the need to **map** the calculation to the property.

Looking at the [javadocs](http://rethinkdb.com/api/java/update/) for update it has **[HashMap](http://rethinkdb.com/api/java/hashmap/)** method which I followed with the [c# library](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver) and it works.

```
 var result = r.Db("test").Table("learning").Get("c8c54346-e35f-4025-8641-7117f12ebc5b").Update(row => r.HashMap("fieldNameIntValue",row["fieldNameIntValue"].Add(1))).Run(_conn);
```

I'd be interested to know if this is the right way or was a better way.

Comment: Looks good. This should work. I think you can also use an anonymous type in place of the hashmap too (extra C# driver feature). Also, I'd follow @T Resudek's suggestion too. If you have any trouble, try to get the query to work in *Data Explorer* and it should be easily translatable to the C# driver. :) Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you please tell me how do you specify in the `table` which field is the `primarykey` ?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example that works in the ReQL data explorer. You can chain as may filters before the update as you want. I assume this will translate to the C# Driver, but I dont have any experience with that.

```
r.db('database').table('tablename').update({clicks: r.row("clicks").add(1)}).run().then(function(result){ ...
```